# Convert integer to balanced dozenal

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

Create a function which takes an integer and returns an array of integers representing the number in [balanced base twelve](http://shwa.org/reverse.htm). Specifically, the representation should follow these rules regarding 6 & -6 (from the above link):

> 1. If the last digit of a number could be written with either **6** or **ϑ**, we use the one whose sign is *opposite* the sign of the first digit. For example, we write decimal ***30*** as dozenal **3ϑ**, but decimal ***-30*** as as dozenal **ε6**, not **ζϑ**.
> 2. If a **6** or **ϑ** occurs before the last digit of a number, we use the one whose sign is *opposite* the next digit after it. For example, we write decimal ***71*** as dozenal **6τ**, but decimal ***73*** as as dozenal **1ϑ1**, not **61**.
> 3. If a **6** or **ϑ** is followed by a **0**, we keep looking to the right until we can apply one of the first two rules. For example, we write decimal ***-72*** as dozenal **τ60**, not **ϑ0**.

Otherwise, the only restrictions are to use only digits in [-6..6], and for the output, when interpreted as big-endian base twelve, to be equivalent to the input.

Example of use:

```
f(215) => [1,6,-1]
f(216) => [2,-6,0]
f(-82) => [-1,5,2]
f(0)   => [0]
```

Winner is the shortest, with upvotes being the tiebreaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>69</strike> <strike>53</strike> 49 characters

```
[.0<\{.12:^%.3$5+>{^-\^+\}*@1$.0<@if@^/.}do;;]-1%
```

GolfScript expression which takes top of the stack and replaces it by the result. You can play with the code [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ewpbLjA8XHsuMTI6XiUuMyQ1Kz57Xi1cXitcfSpAMSQuMDxAaWZAXi8ufWRvOztdLTElCn06ZjsKCjIxNSBmIHAKMjE2IGYgcAoyMTcgZiBwCjcxIGYgcAo3MiBmIHAKNzMgZiBwCi0xOSBmIHAKMCBmIHAK&run=true).

Comment: Working on a different solution which should be much shorter - but unfortunately doesn't work for several corner cases...

Answer (score 3):

### J, <s>74</s> 72 characters

Here's my J implementation (`f =.` not included in character count):

```
f =. **}.^:(*@#*0={.)@([:((12-~[),0>:@{.@]`[`]}])`,@.(6>[)/&.|.0,12&#.^:_1)@|
```

And some tests (each result is boxed, and underscore means negative):

```
   NB. Integers [-10..10]:
   (<@f"0)i:10
┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
│_1 2│_1 3│_1 4│_1 5│_1 6│_5│_4│_3│_2│_1│0│1│2│3│4│5│1 _6│1 _5│1 _4│1 _3│1 _2│
└────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
   NB. Some boundary values:
   (<@f"0)215 216 217 71 72 73 
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬────┬──────┬──────┐
│1 6 _1│2 _6 0│2 _6 1│6 _1│1 _6 0│1 _6 1│
└──────┴──────┴──────┴────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Interestingly, the rules for 6 have no special place in the function. They work that way just by handling all digits >= 6 together and only working on positive numbers.

I made another version, which doesn't rely on `#.^:_1`, but it's longer:

```
**_2&([:}.^:(0={.)+/\)@(((<.@%&12,(1,-&12)`(0,])@.(6>])@(12&|))@{.,}.)^:(0~:{.)^:_)@(,&0)@|
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 71 chars, 142 bytes

```
{⍵=0:,0⋄⍵{⍵=0:⍬⋄((m+⍺×m=0)∇⌊12÷⍨⍵+q),m←t-q←12×(6<t)+(⍺>0)×6=t←12∣⍵}⍨×⍵}
```

test:

```
  z←{⍵=0:,0⋄⍵{⍵=0:⍬⋄((m+⍺×m=0)∇⌊12÷⍨⍵+q),m←t-q←12×(6<t)+(⍺>0)×6=t←12∣⍵}⍨×⍵}
  ⎕fmt z¨215 216 ¯82 0 30 ¯30 71 72 73 ¯72
┌10──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌3──────┐ ┌3──────┐ ┌3──────┐ ┌1─┐ ┌2────┐ ┌2────┐ ┌2────┐ ┌3──────┐ ┌3──────┐ ┌3──────┐│
││ 1 6 ¯1│ │ 2 ¯6 0│ │ ¯1 5 2│ │ 0│ │ 3 ¯6│ │ ¯3 6│ │ 6 ¯1│ │ 1 ¯6 0│ │ 1 ¯6 1│ │ ¯1 6 0││
│└~──────┘ └~──────┘ └~──────┘ └~─┘ └~────┘ └~────┘ └~────┘ └~──────┘ └~──────┘ └~──────┘2
└∊───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```