# The Binary Binary Expansion

Tags: code-golf, integer, binary, base-conversion

> Normally, we decompose a number into binary digits by assigning it with powers of 2, with a coefficient of `0` or `1` for each term:
>
> `25 = 1*16 + 1*8 + 0*4 + 0*2 + 1*1`
>
> The choice of `0` and `1` is... not very binary. We shall perform the *true* binary expansion by expanding with powers of 2, but with a coefficient of `1` or `-1` instead:
>
> `25 = 1*16 + 1*8 + 1*4 - 1*2 - 1*1`
>
> Now *this* looks binary.
>
> Given any positive number, it should be trivial to see that:
>
> - Every odd number has infinitely many true binary expansions
> - Every even number has no true binary expansions
>
> Hence, for a true binary expansion to be well-defined, we require the expansion to be the *least*, i.e with the shortest length.

---

Given any positive, odd integer `n`,  return its true binary expansion, from the most significant digit to the least significant digit (or in reversed order).

#### Rules:

- As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), you should aim to do this in the **shortest byte count possible.** Builtins are allowed.
- Any output that can represent and list the coefficients is acceptable: an array, a string of coefficients with separators, etc...
- Standard golfing loopholes apply.
- Your program should work for values within your language's standard integer size.

---

#### Test Cases

```
25 -> [1,1,1,-1,-1]
47 -> [1,1,-1,1,1,1]
1 -> [1]
3 -> [1,1]
1234567 -> [1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1]
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41752/67312) but quite different.

Comment: Simple algorithm: Convert to base 2, replace 0's with -1's, put the LSD at the front.

Comment: Voile: I wasn't explaining the downvotes, I was just outlining an algorithm for people who have base-conversion commands in their language.

Comment: Since you're so keen on being truly binary, can we return the value as packed bits with the usual place-value but the new interpretation of the two states?  i.e. electrically it's just high or low voltage (or whatever), and it's not my fault if standard debuggers print `0` instead of `-1` for the low-voltage state.  The caller receiving the bits knows what they mean.  (It's still a non-trivial bit-manipulation exercise, since a rotate right only works if it has 32 significant bits.  e.g. a 5-bit number needs a rotate width of 5.)

Comment: Does the output need to include separators? Is `111-1-1` a valid output for `25`?

Comment: @Oliver No separators is also fine, since that list is readable (only `-1` can start with the minus sign).

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure if your language cannot represent the concept of `-1` easily. For regular languages, however, as `-1` is just a number like `0` or any other numbers, there is no particular reasons why one should avoid `-1`.

Comment: @Voile: I want to write a bit-manipulation answer (in x86 assembly machine code: `bsf ecx, edi` / `shr edi,1` / `bts edi, ecx` are 2 and 3 byte instructions), not an answer with a loop that turns bits into string digits or array elements one at a time.  In the latter case, the answer is more boring, and the best way to handle the n-bit rotate is by storing a leading `1` and then looping over the bits in `x >> 1`.

Comment: i.e. I want to return an answer in "true binary", not a string or array representation of it.  I know this is basically asking for a loophole that changes the problem for other languages, too, so I get why you're reluctant to allow it.  I wish that you'd allowed that in the first place.

Comment: @JosiahWinslow, I can see why your algorithm works easily enough by subtracting the two representations and seeing that the result is 0, but is there a succinct proof of it?

Comment: @Jonah: Even though an n-bit rotation works, for understanding why it works, it's probably best to think of it as a right-shift that shifts in a copy of the high bit (like a 2's complement arithmetic shift but for limited width).  Then remember that `1000` - 1 is `0111` (in normal base2 binary).  Transforming from normal binary to "true binary" will require more set bits at the front, to compensate for unset bits meaning subtract their place-value rather than `0`.  (This isn't a proof, but for me it's an "ok, that makes sense", and maybe could be cleaned up into a proof.)

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
¤é r0J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9CSwysVigy8/v83MQcA)

### Explanation:

```
¤é r0J  // Test input:                  25
¤       // Binary the input:            11001
 é      // Rotate 1 chars to the right: 11100
   r0J  // Replace 0s with -1:          111-1-1
```

Comment: Ah, the rotation; *that*'s why it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Rotate??? dagnabbit.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
f=n=>n?[...f(n>>=1),!n|n%2||-1]:[]
```

#### Test snippet

```js
let f=n=>n?[...f(n>>=1),!n|n%2||-1]:[];

[25, 47, 1, 3, 1234567].map(x => console.log(x + ":", JSON.stringify(f(x))))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io),  <s>12</s>  11 bytes

```
|R_1.>jQ2 1
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7CR_1.%3EjQ2+1&input=47&debug=0)**

---

## How?

```
|R_1.>jQ2 1   Full program.

      jQ2      Convert input to a binary list.
     .>   1    Cyclically rotate the list above by 1 place to the right.
|R_1           Substitute 0 with -1.
               Implicitly output.
```

First off, we notice that the task is just "substitute the `0`s in the binary writing with `-1`s and shift to the right by 1 place." — That's exactly what we should do! The binary conversion gives us a list of `0`s and `1`s. All we should do here is to find a golfy way to convert `0` to `-1`. The bitwise operator `|` (bitwise OR) is our friend. The map over the binary representation shifted with `|` and `-1`. If the current number is `0`, it gets converted to `-1`.

Comment: I don't think there's a better way. ;)

Comment: @JosiahWinslow I do... Trying to find it

Comment: Hm? The algorithm seems optimal, maybe that's because I don't know Pyth.

Comment: @JosiahWinslow Found the better way. Syntactical better way, not algorithmic better way.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder And now there really isn't any at least to me.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org)

String version, 31 bytes

```perl6
1~(*+>1).base(2).subst(0,-1,:g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPvfsE5DS9vOUFMvKbE4VcNIU6@4NKm4RMNAR9dQxypd8781F1dxIkithpGppjWMbWKOYBsimMZIokbGJqZmQGX/AQ)

List version, 36 bytes

```perl6
{map * *2-1,1,|($_+>1).base(2).comb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/OjexQEFLQctI11DHUKdGQyVe285QUy8psThVw0hTLzk/N6n2f3EiSLWGkammNReUbWKOYBsimMZIokbGJqZmQGX/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 72 bytes

There is surely a better way, but this is what I have...

```perl6
->$a {grep {$a==[+] @^a.reverse Z+< ^∞},[X] (1,-1)xx $a.base(2).chars}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPtf104lUaE6vSi1QKFaJdHWNlo7VsEhLlGvKLUstag4VSFK20Yh7lHHvFqd6IhYBQ1DHV1DzYoKBZVEvaTE4lQNI0295IzEouLa/9ZcxYkgMzUMDTX/AwA)

**Explanation**: It's a function that takes one argument (`->$a`). We first get the number of coefficients needed (`$a.base(2).chars` = number of characters in base 2 representation), then make a Cartesian product (`X`) of that many pairs `(1,-1)`. (The `[X]` means: reduce the following list with `X`.) So we get a list of all possible combinations of 1s and -1s. Then we filter (`grep`) only the lists which encode the given number `$a`. There is only one, so we get a list of one list with the coefficients.

The grep block does this: takes its argument as a list (`@^a`), reverses it and zips it with an infinite list `0,1,2,...` using the "left bit shift" operator `+<`. Zipping stops as soon as the shorter list is depleted (good for us!) We then sum all the results and compare it with the given number. We had to use `.reverse` because the OP demands that the coefficients be in the order from most significant to least significant.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>90</s> <s>88</s> 46 bytes

```r
function(n)c((n%/%2^(0:log2(n))%%2)[-1],1)*2-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPM1lDI09VX9UoTsPAKic/3QgopKmqaqQZrWsYq2OoqWWka/g/TcNQkytNwxhEGJmCSBNzzf8A)

Implements [Oliver's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141159/67312), but returns the digits in reverse order. Since we are guaranteed that `n` is never even, the least significant bit (the first) is always `1`, so we remove it and append a `1` to the end to simulate rotation in R. Thanks to Shaggy for [getting me to fix my math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141156/the-binary-binary-expansion/141158?noredirect=1#comment346194_141158).

Simply putting `rev( )` around the function calls in the footer should return the values in the same order.

### original answer, 88 bytes:

```r
function(n,b=2^(0:log2(n)))(m=t(t(expand.grid(rep(list(c(-1,1)),sum(b|1))))))[m%*%b==n,]
```

Anonymous function; returns the values in **reverse order** with column names attached.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcbRCoIwFIfx@95D@J9Y0aYmCOdJoqCpk4E7ypzQRe@@2nfx44vZcXaHDMmvAlGWzQu3fllnAyEiBE5ImD7bW8brHP2IOG1Y/J4w4KKVJlL7EWC//ys9QnWuLLOoZ3bQdHKoC6YtNl1Rm7pp7x3lHw)

Explanation:

```r
function(n){
 b <- 2^(0:log2(n))         # powers of 2 less than n
 m <- expand.grid(rep(list(c(-1,1)),sum(b|1))) # all combinations of -1,1 at each position in b, as data frame
 m <- t(t(m))               # convert to matrix
 idx <- m%*%b==n            # rows where the matrix product is `n`
 m[idx,]                    # return those rows
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider that output to be valid; suggest asking the challenge author for confirmation.

Comment: @Shaggy reversed order is explicitly allowed: `from the most significant digit to the least significant digit (or in reversed order).` hence this should be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Reversed *order*, not reversed signs. Meaning valid output for `25`, for example, would be `[1,1,1,-1,-1]` or `[-1,-1,1,1,1]`.

Comment: @Shaggy ah, you're right, I just did the math wrong! should be `2*bits - 1` instead of `1-2*bits`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
bÁ0®:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/6XCjwaF1Vv//G5kCAA)

Comment: `D<` can be `®` (`®` is default `-1`).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks! Didn't realize that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Bṙ-o-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p4c6Zuvm6/w@3H530cOeM//8NjYxNTM3MAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 11 bytes

```
1-~2*_1|.#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03BVk/BULfOSCvesEZP2YqLKzU5I18hTcHIFMYyNDI2MTUz//8fAA)

Thanks to @JosiahWinslow for the algorithm.

Any thoughts on making the conversion shorter? My thoughts are to using `!.`-fit (nvm, it just changes the tolerance of the conversion).

Using `{`-take is longer by 1 character.

```
_1 1{~_1|.#:
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 30 bytes

29 bytes code, 1 byte for `-p` switch.

```perl
$_=sprintf'1%b',$_/2;s/0/-1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4oCgzryRN3VA1SV1HJV7fyLpY30Bf11A//f9/QyNjE1Mz83/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 101 bytes

```java
n->{String s=n.toString(n,2);return(s.charAt(s.length()-1)+s.replaceAll(".$","")).replace("0","-1");}
```

Port of [*@Oliver*'s Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141159/52210), with *a few* more bytes.. ;)

Can definitely be golfed by using an mathematical approach instead of this String approach.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY9Ba8MwDIXv/RXC7GCzxixpux5CBz3u0F52HDt4rpe6dZVgK4VS8tszbcmOIyCBpO/B0zuZq8nqxuHpcO5tMCnBzni8zwA8kotfxjrY/6wAbxQ9VmDlK5PKRUBVMui4uRIZ8hb2gLCBHrOX@6hPG9RUD4vEeaHK6KiNKJO2RxO3xENwWNFRqixXj0lH1wT23YYghX4QcyGU@jtK8cSHLBeq7PpysG7az8DW4wfX2h/gwiHk4Pn@AUaNCW6J3EXXLemGEQWUqK3M1W@Qf/ligherCcFyPSHIi8Vy9TyqulnXfwM)

```java
n->{                             // Method with Integer parameter and String return-type
  String s=n.toString(n,2);      //  Convert the Integer to a binary String
  return(s.charAt(s.length()-1)  //  Get the last character of the binary String
    +s.replaceAll(".$","")       //   + everything except the last character
   ).replace("0","-1");          //  Then replace all zeroes with -1, and return the result
}                                // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>44 37 33</s> 32 bytes

```ruby
->n{("1%b"%n).chop.gsub ?0,"-1"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWkPJUDVJSTVPUy85I79AL724NEnB3kBHSddQqfZ/gUJatJFpLBeINjGP/Q8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Golfscript, <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 14 bytes

*-1 byte because I forgot `%` existed.*
*+1 byte because I also forgot input is a string.*

```
~2base{.+(}%)\
```

Comment: If you're going to assume that the input comes as an integer, you should wrap the code in `{}` to make it a block. Full programs can only get input as strings.

Comment: Um...what? I meant, the number is being pushed as an integer, instead of a string containing a number.

Comment: In that case your answer is not a full program, and so [must be a "function"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/194), or in the case of GolfScript a block. Therefore it's `{2base{.+(}%\}` for 15 bytes. Similarly your CJam answer.

Comment: This is a full program. Input in Golfscript are implicitly pushed onto the stack at the beginning of the program, and input in CJam is specified before execution and accessed with the q command.

Comment: [I do have some familiarity with GolfScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=golfscript+user:194). ([And CJam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=cjam+user%3A194)). If you want to claim that it's a full program you need to prefix it with `~`.

Comment: That I'd specified (I wasn't sure; I hadn't messed with GolfScript in a while, and I used the online interpreter). Will add now.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 12 bytes

A port of my Golfscript answer.

```
qi2b{_+(}%)\
```