# Divide them all

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

A Math.SE user have a funny game explained as such:

> 1. Pick a random positive integer X.
> 2. Add +1, 0, -1 to make it divisible by 3<sup>Keep track of how much you've added and subtracted. That is your "score".</sup>.
> 3. Divide by 3 to create a new X.
> 4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you reach one.

I'm expecting the shortest code to give the correct score and the decomposition (as a list of the following values [+1;0;-1]) given an integer input.

```
Input => Expected score => Expected decomposition #explanation
12 => -1 => 0-1 #(12/3 => (4 - 1) / 3 = 1
                             ^^^
25 => 0 => -1+10  (25 - 1) / 3 => (8 + 1) / 3 => (3 + 0) / 3 => 1
                      ^^^            ^^^            ^^^

9320 => -1 => +1+1-10-1+1-1-1 #(9320 + 1) / 3 => (3107 + 1) / 3 => (1036 - 1) / 3 => (345 + 0) /3 => (115 - 1) / 3 => (38 + 1) / 3 => (13 - 1) / 3 => (4 - 1) / 3
                                     ^^^               ^^^               ^^^              ^^^             ^^^             ^^^             ^^^            ^^^
```

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41752/8478) (This challenge basically asks for the sum of digits of the balanced ternary representation.)

Comment: @MartinEnder it even sounds like a dup... I should enlarge my vocabulary in order to find them more easily. Thanks.

Comment: I personally don't think it's a dupe because the expected output isn't the bal-ternary representation so you still have to do a slightly different task. Very related though, I agree.

Comment: Does our code have to include the "pick a random positive integer" part or can we take the number as input?

Comment: @nimi I think that _"given an integer input"_ overrides what's said in the quote from Math.SE.

Comment: Suggested test cases: `121: [ -1, -1, -1, -1 ] --> -4`, `122: [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] --> 5`

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, asking for the decomposition and its sum is a pretty minor variant on asking for the decomposition.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I may be misinterpreting the challenge, but asking for the decomposition and asking for the digits seem like completely different tasks to me...

Comment: @Arnauld you're right about 12, and the fact that the ouptut code must give both score & decomposition. I'll make my next questions proof-read

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, isn't the decomposition just the digits? Actually, on trying it, it seems to be the digits (except the leading +1) reversed. That's possibly accumulating enough trivial modifications (skip the first digit, reverse, also output the sum) to add up to something non-trivial, but it's still borderline.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I personally think that finding the decomposition on its own is much more competitive than finding the digits and then doing that whole reversal procedure, but it is a very similar challenge and doesn't really add too much new to the existing challenge

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

Returns an array where:

- the last term is the sum
- all preceding terms are the decomposition

```javascript
f=(n,s=0)=>n-1?[k=1-++n%3,...f(n/3|0,s+k)]:[s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY2xDoIwFEV3v@ItJm3oK31FBk2KH0IYCIJRSGuscfLfKwhilMTkDnc4J@dc3ktfXU@XG1p3qENoDLPCG8VNZpH2eWsIo8iuEyGlbJiNk4cSPmp5sct9ESpnvetq2bkjaxhpzgEgjiEHJQAJCkDM@rP6BnX6AZEE9FMTq37QbaJVD7/QkRwEJd4e0r8QaRpKcwgXxmZh6NkYC9MmIQ1P)

Comment: Unless I'm misreading the spec/test cases, it doesn't look like you need to include the total in the output.

Comment: @Shaggy I don't really know for sure. I've asked the OP.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

Credit to Mr.Xcoder

```python
f=lambda i,*s:i>1and f(-~i//3,*s,1--~i%3)or[s,sum(s)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVNHq9gq084wMS9FIU1Dty5TX98YKKRjqAtkqxpr5hdFF@sUl@ZqFGvG/i/PyMxJVTC0Uigoyswr0UjTAJGZeQWlJRqaQPDf0IjLyJTL0MgQiI24LI2NDAA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
f=lambda i,s=[]:i>1and f(-~i/3,s+[1--~i%3])or[s,sum(s)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYZBCsMgEADvvsJLQakh3ZUeGkg/Ih4sqWQhMZI1lF76dWMHZpj8LfOWsNY4LmF9TUGS4dH5gZ4Q0iSj6n7UW8NXB13bi/V62x0bPlbF2tfPTMtbwiDzTqmoqP6llI@idKMCCrwLQGiieFi8nQ)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
i,s=input(),[]
while~-i:s+=1--~i%3,;i=-~i/3
print s,sum(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SqmCroKSk9D9Tp9g2M6@gtERDUyc6lqs8IzMntU4306pY29ZQV7cuU9VYxzrTFsjQN@YqKMrMK1Eo1ikuzdUo1vwP1M6VWpGarAAyTsv0v6ERl5Epl6GRIRAbcVkaGxkAAA)

Returns list with decomposition and sum of it

Comment: [53 bytes in Python 3 using recursion](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVNHq9gq084wMS9FIU1Dty5TX98YKKRjqAtkqxpr5hdFF@sUl@ZqFGvG/i/PyMxJVTC0Uigoyswr0UjTAJGZeQWlJRqaQPDf0IjLyJTL0MgQiI24LI2NDAA). The Python 2 equivalent recursive function should be about 55 bytes long. Keeping this as a Python 2 full program, `while~-i` saves a byte.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks! Don't you want to post Python 3 solution as separate answer?

Comment: You're welcome! No, I'm good. Go ahead and use it however you want.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder So there will be all solutions with credit to you :D